# Sample from a list of data.frames

Tags: r, list

I have the following `list1` and `list2`:

```
df1   <- data.frame(x=(1:3),Q=(3:5))
df2   <- data.frame(x=(1:3),Q=(3:5))
df3   <- data.frame(x=(1:3),Q=(3:5))
list1 <- list(df1,df2,df3)
list2 <- list(2,3,6)
```

I want to sample randomly from `Q` in each `list1` element according to the corresponding value in 
 `list2`

So I would sample from `Q` 2 times for the first pair of list elements.

So far I have managed:

```
df1   <- data.frame(x=(1:3),Q=(3:5))
z <- 2
sapply(1:z,function(i) sample(df1$Q,1))
```

but I am struggling at trying to `mapply` this across both all pairs of elements in both lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a `mapply` approach:

```
mapply(function(x, y) sample(x[["Q"]], y, replace = TRUE), list1, list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're after but it may help :

```
FUN <- function(x, z) sapply(1:z,function(i) sample(x[["Q"]], 1))
lapply(seq_along(list1), function(i) FUN(list1[[i]], list2[[i]]))
```